# Need help translating vb.net line to be strict proof

Tags: vb.net, strict

I am having issues with translating this vb.net line into a strict proof one

```
[Enum].GetValues(GetType(ReferenceOutput))(DataGrid1.SelectedIndex)
```

ReferenceOutput is a class and the datagrid1.selectedindex is the one selected in the datagrid . How do I translate this into a strict proof line. I get followin error now.

```
Error   1   Option Strict On disallows late binding.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most robust approach would be to use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx) which is a new generic method:

```
Dim refOutput As ReferenceOutput
Dim enumValue = DataGrid1.SelectedIndex.ToString()
If [Enum].TryParse(enumValue, refOutput) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", enumValue, refOutput.ToString())
Else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a member of the ReferenceOutput enumeration.", enumValue)
End If
```

This is the old verbose, unchecked unboxing approach:

```
Dim refOutput As ReferenceOutput = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(ReferenceOutput), DataGrid1.SelectedIndex.ToString(), True), ReferenceOutput)
```